# .ag-cell menu background color (Angular)

Tags: css, angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I have customized the ag-cell background color of the ag-theme-balham

After that change, the menu that shows when right clicking on a cell also changed; it became transparent.

How can I define the background-color of that cell menu?

I cannot figure out the name of the class to use to be able to override the color.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve that by `.ag-menu` with theme class reference :

```
.ag-theme-balham .ag-menu {
    background-color: #c11515;
    color: #000;
}
```

Don't forget to change menu icon color:

```
.ag-menu > .ag-icon {
    color: #c5e030;
}
```